# ClickMagick Tracking Code Not Detected When Using LiteSpeed Cache Guest Mode Optimization

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, litespeed, gtmetrix, click-tracking

help me out with a bug when using Hostinger + Litespeed Cache and ClickMagick cmc.js in Wordpress

This is the page getting the issue:
https://love.conscientia.net/3-marriage-mistakes-n1-h3/

Following this video guideline to configure Litespeed Cache
https://youtu.be/drC7cgDP3vU?t=271

at 4:31 he suggests activating Guest Mode and "Guest Optimization"
and it greatly improves my pagespeed load...

BUT... it breaks my tracking code that loads in head section:

```
<script>
    window.clickmagick_cmc = {
        uid: '180011',
        hid: '3176839096',
        cmc_project: 'FB Save Marriage',
        vid_info: 'on',
        cmc_ref: 'N1-h3-i1',
        utm_source: 'organic',
    utm_campaign: 'N1-h3-i1',
    }
</script>
<script src='//cdn.clkmc.com/cmc.js'></script>
```

[screenshot of clickmagick code in head of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPsst.png)

**code is not detected** only if i use "Guest Optimization" - and im not sure why that is happening
i asked the tracking software ClickMagick that uses that **cmc.js** and they told me this:

> I'd suggest reaching out to your hosting provider on increasing page speed, especially if turning off guest mode and guest optimize fixes the issue (may also need to reach out to the creators of the plugin, since it is an issue with their plugin)

> As far as **organics** go... that would only be tracked if people make it to your page without UTMs source, medium and campaign.

I'm getting **organic traffic** because **cmc.js** is not being loaded properly when guest optimize is active, so people are not getting proper UTMs source, medium and campaign.

by the way, i already tried using the Excluding cmc.js from the litespeed cache - but it's not working.

[screenshot of litespeed cache exclusion cmc.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww7F5.png)

[With guest optimize active i get **1.4s** of page loading time.](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/love.conscientia.net/KD0u9JfX/)

[without guest optimize pageload time is at **3.7s** (double)](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/love.conscientia.net/mDmaLegc/)

*With guest optimize, cmc.js is not detected - hence i cannot track my traffic.*

With guest otimize, cmc.js is detected but *pagespeed load doubles*.

Any idea how to fix this?

P.S. here's what "Guest Optimize" do:
https://docs.litespeedtech.com/lscache/lscwp/general/#guest-optimization

Summary:
I've tried to Improve Pagespeed Loading times at gtmetrix and lightspeed google by using LiteSpeed Cache plugin recommended as default in Hostinger service. With Wordpress and Avada Theme.

I run traffic from facebook ads with UTM parameters into my site, and ClickMagick's javascript cmc.js collects the traffic data so i can see what variation of ad works.

unluckily, there's a conflict between litespeed cache guest mode's options and getting traffic tracking to work.